# Look for specific date range across multiple files in a folder and copy to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a vba code to help filter a specific range of date. The start date and end date are found in the initial worksheet on the cell B2 and B3. 
As long as the data worksheet in column H (which is the date column) has a date fall between the start and end date in the initial worksheet, then the entire row will be copied and paste on a new worksheet.

I have no idea how to write a vba code so to search for the date according to cell B2 and B3 and copy out the data. Please have a look again:

```
Sub TransfertootherbranchOverall()
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long


' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\CMSNY\Desktop\Salary\Teacher's Files"



' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
' in the search folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

' Set various application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
rnum = 1


     ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next

            ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
            With mybook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

**'this is where I stuck to put in a code**

            End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                ' If source range uses all columns then
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else




                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount

                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next FNum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you removed all the extraneous information, and only ask specifically about the issue you're having. Also, instead of dumping all your code, only show what's necessary. Right now it's difficult to parse your actual question from all the noise, so to speak. I've skimmed your post twice and still don't get what it is you're asking. So I'm just going to move on.

Comment: Thank you, I have amended and shorten the question to very specific. Thought giving the entire picture would be clearer but turn out to be more confusing.

Comment: It would help if you could show one or two examples of input and desired output.